# How do you run pyflink scripts on AWS EMR?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am struggling to run the basic `word_count.py` pyflink [example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-python/pyflink/examples/table/word_count.py) that comes loaded with the apache flink on AWS EMR

Steps taken:

1. Successfully created AWS EMR 6.5.0 cluster with the following applications [Flink, Zookeeper] - verified that there is a `flink` and `flink-yarn-session` binary in `$PATH`. AWS says it installed `v1.14`.
2. Ran the java version successfully by doing the following

- `sudo flink-yarn-sessions`
- `sudo flink run -m yarn-cluster -yid <application_id> /usr/lib/flink/examples/batch/WordCount.jar`

3. Tried running the same with the python but no dice

- `sudo flink run -m yarn-cluster -yid <application_id> -py /usr/lib/flink/examples/python/table/word_count.py`

This fails but error makes it obvious that its picking up `python2.7` even though `python3` is default!!

4. Fixed the issue by somewhat following this [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/downloads/setup-pyflink-virtual-env.sh). Then tried with a simple example to print out `sys.version`. This confirmed that its picking up my python version
5. Try again with venv

- `sudo flink run -m yarn-cluster -yid <application_id> -pyarch file:///home/hadoop/venv.zip -pyclientexec venv.zip/venv/bin/python3 -py /usr/lib/flink/examples/python/table/word_count.py`

At this point, I start seeing various issues ranging from `no file found` to mysterious

```
pyflink.util.exceptions.TableException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
```

I ran various permutation of with/without yarn cluster. But no progress made thus far.

I am thinking my issues are either environment related (why isn't AWS taking care of proper python version is beyond me) or my inexperience with yarn/pyflink.

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you do. To make a cluster:

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-6.5.0 --applications Name=Flink --configurations file://./config.json --region us-west-2 --log-uri s3://SOMEBUCKET --instance-type m5.xlarge --instance-count 2 --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --ec2-attributes KeyName=YOURKEYNAME,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Jar=command-runner.jar,Name=Flink_Long_Running_Session,Args=flink-yarn-session,-d
```

Contents of config.json:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "flink-conf",
    "Properties": {
      "python.executable": "python3",
      "python.client.executable": "python3"
    },
    "Configurations": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Then once you are in, try this

```
sudo flink run -m yarn-cluster -yid YID -py /usr/lib/flink/examples/python/table/batch/word_count.py
```

You can find the YID in the AWS EMR console under application user interfaces.