# Not able to run simple pyflink word_count.py on aws emr

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-emr, pyflink

I have created an EMR cluster (v5.35.0) and am trying to run a sample word_count.py to verify if I am able to execute a flink job.
I am able to use python3 as mentioned in this question [How do you run pyflink scripts on AWS EMR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910061/how-do-you-run-pyflink-scripts-on-aws-emr)

Using the below command to submit the job from /usr/lib/flink on the master node

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster  --python examples/python/table/word_count.py
```

but I run into the following error

```
Executing word_count example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/python/table/word_count.py", line 146, in <module>
    word_count(known_args.input, known_args.output)
  File "examples/python/table/word_count.py", line 121, in word_count
    .execute_insert('sink') \
  File "/usr/lib/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/table/table_result.py", line 76, in wait
  File "/usr/lib/flink/opt/python/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1286, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/flink/opt/python/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o100.await.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.awaitInternal(TableResultImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.await(TableResultImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(TableResultImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.isFirstRowReady(TableResultImpl.java:383)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.lambda$awaitInternal$1(TableResultImpl.java:116)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 8064c1bde7be5c84d7086c13da8cb82b)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:54)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 8064c1bde7be5c84d7086c13da8cb82b)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:403)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$26(RestClusterClient.java:698)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:403)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:575)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:943)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:123)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:228)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:209)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to execute the command: python3 -c import pyflink;import os;print(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(pyflink.__file__)), 'bin'))
output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyflink'

    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.execute(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:211)
    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.getPythonUdfRunnerScript(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.python.env.beam.ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.createEnvironment(ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createPythonExecutionEnvironment(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.lambda$open$0(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:243)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.lambda$getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory$5(MemoryManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.createResource(SharedResources.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.getOrAllocateSharedResource(SharedResources.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.AbstractStatelessFunctionOperator.open(AbstractStatelessFunctionOperator.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.table.PythonTableFunctionOperator.open(PythonTableFunctionOperator.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:711)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:687)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:654)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I have choosen spark, hadoop, flink, presto, zookeeper as the frameworks.
It works without a glitch if I use WordCount.jar but doesn't work for word_count.py

I am not sure why it shows that pyflink module is not found. I also installed apache flink again on the master node using pip as a last ditch effort but the same error occurs

```
pip install apache-flink==1.14
```

Any pointers would be helpful

**Update 1:**

I was able to solve this by getting help from AWS Support. They asked me to create a separate venv and install the dependencies. If you look into the yarn log file for that application id, you would also get the stacktrace.